# javax.validation.ValidationException: Service Object is null in RESTful webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, validation, cxf, bean-validation

I am trying to implement input validations for JSON POST request for my REST API. I am using Bean Validation API and @NotNull annotation. When I remove the validation configuration my API works fine but with Bean Validation API it throws **javax.validation.ValidationException: Service Object is null**  exception.
My configurations are

```
<jaxrs:server id="accrualService" address="/accrualService">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="accrualWebService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>   
     <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:features>
        <ref bean="commonValidationFeature" />
    </jaxrs:features>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        <!--To generate Error response in case of exception -->
        <bean class="com.webservice.exceptions.AccrualServiceExceptionMapper" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="commonValidationFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationFeature" />
<bean id="accrualWebService" class="com.webservices.impl.AccrualWebServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="accrualWebServiceManager" ref="accrualWebServiceManager"/>
</bean>
```

My cxf version is 2.5.2 and cxf-rt-core version is 2.5.2.
I have used @NotNull annotation which is not working for me. Am I missing something is configurations and how can I implement the input validation successfully using annotaion only?

Comment: Which CXF Version are you using? You shouldn't mix 2.x and 3.x dependencies. Update both to 3.1.12 and check the docs: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html

Comment: You may consider removing the package name implying the company (com.loylogic.loyconnect) before posting the question – companies usually frown upon that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @MayurSoni , did you find a solution for this issue? I am having the same kind of problem.

Comment: @nilsmagnus you have to add these dependencies in your pom
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
Also exclude spring-asm and spring-expression dependency from your apache-cxf dependency.